# 204 code message No Content response in retrofit

Tags: retrofit2

When I request to web Service, with use Retrofit2 library I got a This message **204 code message No Content response** is it caused by callback method or caused by web services, I used below request method, how can I solve this problem?

```
Call<Response<Void>> call = dgPosRemoteRepository.getKdvList(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response<Void>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Response<Void>> call, Response<Response<Void>> response) {
        Log.i("", "onResponse: " + response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Response<Void>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i("", "onResponse: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```